# How to Make the Table like the Given Design in the Image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, google-web-designer

```css
.table.bw-pedigree {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 960px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 450px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile td, .table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile th {
  width: auto;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile td span, .table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile th span {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line {
  bottom: 0;
  background: #3d3528;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line:before {
  background: #3d3528;
  width: 2px;
  height: 18px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -18px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col1-line {
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col1-line:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #3d3528;
  border-right: 2px solid #3d3528;
  height: 20px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col2-line {
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col2-line:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #3d3528;
  border-right: 2px solid #3d3528;
  height: 20px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col3-line {
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col3-line:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #3d3528;
  border-right: 2px solid #3d3528;
  height: 20px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree td, .table.bw-pedigree th {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  color: #3d3528;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.table.bw-pedigree td span, .table.bw-pedigree th span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #C9AE83;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="table bw-pedigree bw-pedigree-mobile">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="td-title-1">
        <span>Omega Hymn to the Sea</span>
        <div class="col-line col1-line"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="td-title-2 tit2">
        <span>MAGIC MAGNIFIQUE</span>
        <div class="col-line col2-line"></div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="4" class="td-title-2 tit2-1">
        <span>OMEGA SEAPRINCESS</span>
        <div class="col-line col2-line tit2-2"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="td-title-3 tit3">
        <span>TRUE COLOURS</span>
        <div class="col-line col3-line"></div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" class="td-title-3 tit3-2">
        <span>MAGIC MON AMOUR</span>
        <div class="col-line col3-line"></div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" class="td-title-3">
        <span>EL AMIN</span>
        <div class="col-line col3-line"></div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" class="td-title-3">
        <span>AVALON MISST</span>
        <div class="col-line col3-line"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="td-title-3">
        <span>THEE DESPERADO</span>
      </td>
      <td class="td-title-3">
        <span>DAHEDA</span>
      </td>
      <td class="td-title-3">
        <span>WINDSPREES MIRAGE</span>
      </td>
      <td class="td-title-3">
        <span>AL AMRYA</span>
      </td>
      <td class="td-title-3">
        <span>PSYTADEL</span>
      </td>
      <td class="td-title-3">
        <span> RA COOL ELYGANCE</span>
      </td>
      <td class="td-title-3">
        <span>ESSTEEM</span>
      </td>
      <td class="td-title-3">
        <span>MISS MAE</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to make table like this, but I don't know how can I create row with rotated text. What is a good way to design the table? I don't have much experience in table design. I know a lot about responsive design in HTML/CSS and decided to try to code the periodic table of elements using HTML/CSS in order to practice. I have the basic structure of the table (using mostly `div` elements), but I'm majorly lacking a responsive flow.

[image: Table]

Comment: please show us your code and what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/5py8akz7/7/

hope this might help, use the below code to rotate the text inside the table. Also share with us some code, that you have tried....

```
.verticalTableHeader {
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    
}
.verticalTableHeader:before {
    content:'';
    padding-top:110%;/* takes width as reference, + 10% for faking some extra padding */
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Writing-mode` would be a start .

I removed also position:absolute and size to `spans` to show the idea

```css
.table.bw-pedigree {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 960px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 450px;
  border-spacing:1em 0.5em
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile td, .table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile th {
  width: auto;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile td span, .table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile th span {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line {
  bottom: 0;
  background: #3d3528;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line:before {
  background: #3d3528;
  width: 2px;
  height: 18px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -18px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col1-line {
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col1-line:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #3d3528;
  border-right: 2px solid #3d3528;
  height: 20px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col2-line {
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col2-line:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #3d3528;
  border-right: 2px solid #3d3528;
  height: 20px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col3-line {
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree.bw-pedigree-mobile .col-line.col3-line:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #3d3528;
  border-right: 2px solid #3d3528;
  height: 20px;
}

.table.bw-pedigree td, .table.bw-pedigree th {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  color: #3d3528;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.table.bw-pedigree td span, .table.bw-pedigree th span {





  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #C9AE83;
  text-align: center;
}
td span {writing-mode:vertical-lr;margin: auto;}
```

```html
<table class="table bw-pedigree bw-pedigree-mobile">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="8" class="td-title-1">
                  <span>Omega Hymn to the Sea</span>
                  <div class="col-line col1-line"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="td-title-2 tit2">
                  <span>MAGIC MAGNIFIQUE</span>
                  <div class="col-line col2-line"></div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="4" class="td-title-2 tit2-1">
                  <span>OMEGA SEAPRINCESS</span>
                  <div class="col-line col2-line tit2-2"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="td-title-3 tit3">
                  <span>TRUE COLOURS</span>
                  <div class="col-line col3-line"></div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="td-title-3 tit3-2">
                  <span>MAGIC MON AMOUR</span>
                  <div class="col-line col3-line"></div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="td-title-3">
                  <span>EL AMIN</span>
                  <div class="col-line col3-line"></div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="td-title-3">
                  <span>AVALON MISST</span>
                  <div class="col-line col3-line"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="td-title-3">
                  <span>THEE DESPERADO</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-title-3">
                  <span>DAHEDA</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-title-3">
                  <span>WINDSPREES MIRAGE</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-title-3">
                  <span>AL AMRYA</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-title-3">
                  <span>PSYTADEL</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-title-3">
                  <span> RA COOL ELYGANCE</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-title-3">
                  <span>ESSTEEM</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-title-3">
                  <span>MISS MAE</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
```